# Error in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

My Laravel query builder return null:

```
    $country = DB::table('participate_company')

        ->join('company', 'company.company_id', '=', 'participate_company.company_id')
        ->join('country', 'country.country_id', '=', 'company', 'company.country_id')
        ->join('competition', 'competition.competition_id', '=', 'participate_company.competition_id')

        ->select('country.country_name', DB::raw('COUNT(company.country_id) as total'))
        ->groupBy('company.country_id')
        ->groupBy('country.country_name')
        ->get();
```

**Table design:**

**1. Participate_company**

competition_id (pk/fk)
company_id (pk/fk)

**2. company**

company_id (pk) 
company_name 
country_id (fk)

**3. country**

country_id (pk) 
country_name

**4. competition**

competition_id (pk)
competition_year

I want to produce result of count distinct country based on competition year. For example competition year = 2012, country_name = England, count(total) = 20. But my current query produce null.

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2092f/1

Comment: Please put a selection of your data on a [fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com) and I'd be happy to take a look at it. Thank you...

Comment: @hd1 I had edit my post and add sql fiddle ... please take a look on it thank you

Comment: what results are you expecting from that query? I was able to get "England"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Laravel ORM Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) and [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to solve this problem.
In Company model, we would define `country()`method:

```
public function country() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id', 'id');
}
```

In Competition model, define method

```
public function company() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
}
```

So in controller you can call `groupBy` :

```
Competition::with('company:id,country_id')->get()->groupBy('year');
```

We will catch `country_id` in each `company` which is in `relations` of `years`.
I just tested a simple example, after that, we will loop over this collection and count them .

[image: Simple example]

Hope this's usefull.

P/s. As using by models, my table's names: `companies`, `countries`, `competitions`, `company_competition`